# Ckeditor Fixed HTML Structure

Tags: html, ckeditor

Is it possible to have a fixed structure for the HTML using CKEditor. For example, HTML5 placeholders are shown in editor as user hints so user know where to enter what content. Further, it should be possible that user shouldn't be able to change the structure.

An example structure may look like this and placeholder text is shown till user enters the text.

## Title Only

....

...

...

As mentioned above, user shouldn't be able to change the structure/order of the sections.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for a CKEditor **widget**.

In short, widgets are special rich content units in that they are groups of elements which are treated as a single entity inside the editor. Once developed, their structure (but not necessarily their content) is immutable and enforced by the CKEditor instance they are used in. These entities can thus be selected and deleted or moved freely as a whole around the editing area, keeping their predefined structure intact. At the same time all the individual parts of the widget (its "building blocks") can be edited or configured separately, again, without affecting the whole widget entity and its structure in the process. Read more here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_widgets

In your case, you could have a look at the sample Simple Box widget which is [demoed here](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/simplebox.html) and actually created step-by-step in [this tutorial](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1). It creates a simple template widget with an immutable structure and pre-defined fields for the users to fill in. What's more, thanks to [ACF](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf) (CKEditor content filtering mechanism) you are even able to define the elements (and their attributes, styles, classes) that are allowed in each of the widget parts.

Widgets are a really powerful tool, you can see some other implementations of the widget API in the [widget demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets).